# Separating a class into cpp and header file (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

im new to C++ language.
So I was assigned to split an existing file into three source code: swap.h, swap.cpp and source3.cpp

Existing File:

```
#include <iostream>

void get_numbers (int&, int&);
void swap_values (int&, int&);
void show_results (int, int);

int main () {
   int first_num, second_num;

   get_numbers (first_num, second_num);
   swap_values (first_num, second_num);
   show_results (first_num, second_num);
   return 0;
}

void get_numbers (int& input1, int& input2) {
   using namespace std;
   cout << "Enter two integers: ";
   cin >> input1 >> input2;
}

void swap_values (int& variable1, int& variable2) {
   int temp;
   temp = variable1;
   variable1 = variable2;
   variable2 = temp;
}

void show_results (int output1, int output2) {
   using namespace std;
   cout << "In reverse order the numbers are: "
        << output1 << " " << output2 << endl;
}
```

1. swap.h contains function prototypes
2. swap.cpp contains function implementations
3. source3.cpp contains the main function

for swap.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef swap_h
#define swap_h

void get_numbers(int&, int&);
void swap_values(int&, int&);
void show_results(int, int);
#endif
```

for swap.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>

    void get_numbers(int& input1, int& input2) {
       using namespace std;
       cout << "Enter two integers: ";
       cin >> input1 >> input2;
    }

    void swap_values(int& variable1, int& variable2) {
        int temp;
        temp = variable1;
        variable1 = variable2;
        variable2 = temp;
    }

    void show_results(int output1, int output2) {
       using namespace std;
       cout << "In reverse order the numbers are: "
       << output1 << " " << output2 << endl;
    }
```

for source3.cpp:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "swap.h"
    int main()
    {
       int first_num, second_num;

       get_numbers(first_num, second_num);
       swap_values(first_num, second_num);
       show_results(first_num, second_num);
       return 0;
    }
```

When I debug the program, it says: "Unable to start program 'C:\User......'
The system cannot find the file specified. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which file? post the ending part of that path..

Comment: This is going to be hard to reproduce. It compiles for me, had to remove the Visual Studio-isms because I don't have access to MSVC at the moment, and seems to run and behave the way I'd expect. Edit your question and paste in the contents of the output window. Maybe someone will see something out of the ordinary and offer a usable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code compiles successfully, but cannot be started, you probably have problems related to your debugging environment.

Also, you don't need `#ifdef`, `#define`, and `#endif` once you have `#pragma once`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you provided is the whole code, you didn't include `swap.h` in `swap.cpp`. Therefore you have the definition of the functions, but no declaration. Although I would imagine another error or at least a warning here. Try to fix that.

If it doesn't work, try building the Release Version. Does it compile? Does it start? And when it is starting, does it do anything? If what I mentioned before is the problem, I would expect the program to just run to the end, without doing anything.

If the problem lies with `swap.h` in the main File, make sure it is in the same location, or the include paths point to the directory which contains it. Same goes for `stdafx.h`

Also, you don't need `#pragma once` and `#ifndef` `#define` and `#endif`. Get rid of either of those, I recommend using `#ifndef` `#define` and `#endif`, because `#pragma once` is not supported everywhere. But for you it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Nothing in swap.cpp requires anything in swap.h, so no error or warning will be generated. All swap.h goes it advertise the features accessible within swap.cpp.

Comment: True, thx for clearification, but I'd expected a warning like 'No definition of function' or smth like that, not in swap.cpp but in source3.cpp. Not sure if smth like this exists though.  Nevertheless without either swap.h in swap.cpp or swapp.cpp in source3.cpp(which shouldn't be done) the Code will do nothing.